# What happens with a domain name when the "Whois registration-expiration" date is reached?

Tags: domain-name

I'm interested in a domain-name (.com) that is about to expire. What happens when the registration-expiration date is reached?

Comment: A squatter snatches it up and puts it up for sale for $US5,000.

Answer (score 1):

After the expiration date is reached, usually the *registrar* (the entity that takes care of registering that domain and who associates it with you) keeps the domain on hold for 1~2 months (can be more or less), having you (the current owner) as the priority-subscriber/renewer during that time.

In other terms, the domain is not yours anymore (for instance the top-level-domains DNS delegations are not directed to your DNS entries) but only you may register/renew it.

After that *grace* period is over, *registrars* follow one of the following scenarios

- the domain is *back to Nature*, does not *belong* to anybody and anyone can register it from any registrar (the domain may simply be deleted)
- while the domain can be registered by anyone, the domain is kept on hold by the registrar who *knows* that domain is likely to be registered by someone else soon
- some registrars do that: if the domain is considered 'hot', after the grace period they may open a kind of auction, leaving the domain to the highest bid. For instance if you *own* `nature.com` and you don't renew it, it is likely that such an interesting domain will find plenty of *buyers*, and the registrar may want to make the highest amount of money from it.

Comment: **NB** depending on the top level domain (`.com` vs. `.au` vs ...) the rules can change.